# What happens when evaluating `int x = -2147483648`?

Tags: c, type-conversion, integer

What happens when evaluating

```
int x = -2147483648
```

?

1. When evaluating `-2147483648`, `2147483648` is a integer constant which has long type not int, so the result -2147483648 of evaluating `-2147483648` is of type long, not int.
2. When evaluating the assignment "int x = ...", the RHS is value -2147483648 of long type, which is in the range of `x`'s type `int`.  Will value -2147483648 be implicitly converted from long to int, and the conversion keep the value  -2147483648 unchanged?

Comment: Is your #1 a question or an assertion? It reads like an assertion.

Comment: Note the definition `#define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)` is done because `2147483648` is not an `int` value, so it can't be negated as `int`. On my machine  `-2147483648` is type `long long` because `long` is the same as `int` (which it can be).

Comment: I downvoted this because it's your **fourth** re-ask of the same duplicate that keeps getting closed, but in a different form that hides that you really want to know about this in the context of `-2147483648` as a (wrong) definition for `INT_MIN`.

Comment: "2147483648 is a integer constant which has long type not int," --> maybe.  It might need to be type `long long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer presumes the C implementation uses a 32-bit `int` and a 64-bit `long`.

C 2018 6.4.4.1 says “The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.” In the table that follows, the entry for decimal constants with no suffix contains the list `int`, `long int`, `long long int`. Since a `long int` is the first of those that can represent 2,147,483,648, `2147483648` has the type `long int`.

Per 6.5.3.3 3, the result of `-` is the promoted type. The integer promotions (6.3.1.1 2) have no effect on `long int`. So the type of `-2147483648` is `long int`.

Per 6.7.9 11, the value of the initializer is converted as in simple assignment. Per 6.5.16.1 2 and 6.5.16 3, the value is converted to the type of the object being assigned would have after lvalue conversion. That is, for an assignment to an `int` object, the type is an `int` value.

Per 6.3.1.3 1, when converting a value of integer type to another integer type, if the new type can represent the value, it is unchanged. Since `int` can represent −2,147,483,648, it is unchanged.

Therefore, the result of `int x = -2147483648;` is that `x` is initialized with the value −2,147,483,648.

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis in this question is right. Because the value is in the range of `int` and is converted to `int` as part of the initialization (note: the same would happen for assignment), everything works as intended.

As for the hidden part of your question you didn't ask, since it keeps getting closed as a duplicate, this does not mean you can define `INT_MIN` as `-2147483648`. The magic is in the `=` (as assignment operator or a token in the initialization construct). In contexts where it's not being used, there are all sorts of ways that `-2147483648` having type `long` or `long long` rather than `int` breaks semantic requirements on `INT_MIN`. For example:

- `(INT_MIN < 0U) == 0` (because both operands are promoted to `unsigned`), but
- `(-2147483648 < 0U) == 1` (because both operands are promoted to `long` or `long long`).

Comment: In your example, isn't `(-2147483648 < 0U) == 1` expected, while `(INT_MIN < 0U) == 0` surprising? What is your justification for not using `-2147483648`?

Comment: @Tim: The question is not whether it's surprising but whether it's the required behavior. If `INT_MIN` expands to an expression of type `int` whose value is the minimum possible value of type `int`, **as it is specified and thus required to**, then `INT_MIN < 0U` is necessarily false.

Comment: I asked the question in the other post.  it  is  whether it's surprising and what  is wrong about it.

Comment: @Tim: You've asked it 3+ times and it's been closed as duplicate 3+ times. It's wrong because the specification says the expression it expands to has type `int` and thus a correct program can rely on **any** consequence of it having type `int`, including the example in my answer.

Comment: @Tim: Every one of them has been a variant on "why can't `INT_MAX` be defined as X?" where X is `-2147483648`, `0x80000000`, or some other expression that has either the wrong type or the wrong value or both.

Comment: To expand on what @dbush said, if you're not happy with the existing question/answer when your question is closed as a duplicate, **don't re-ask it under a disguise** with the actual thing you want to know buried. Instead clarify how your question is different and what it is you still want to know.