# Is `declarator = initializer` in a declaration an assignment expression?

Tags: c, variable-assignment, declaration

In the C11 standard

> 6.5.16  Assignment operators Syntax
>
> ```
> assignment-expression:
> conditional-expression
> unary-expression  assignment-operator  assignment-expression
>
> assignment-operator: one of = *= /= %= += -= <<=  >>=  &=  ^=  |=
> ```
>
> 6.7  Declarations
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> declaration:
> declaration-speciﬁers init-declarator-listopt ;
> static_assert-declaration
> ```

> ```
> declaration-speciﬁers:
> storage-class-speciﬁer  declaration-speciﬁersopt
> type-speciﬁer  declaration-speciﬁersopt
> type-qualiﬁer  declaration-speciﬁersopt
> function-speciﬁer  declaration-speciﬁersopt
> alignment-speciﬁer  declaration-speciﬁersopt
> ```

> ```
> init-declarator-list:
> init-declarator
> init-declarator-list , init-declarator
> ```

> ```
> init-declarator:
> declarator
> declarator = initializer
> ```

Is `=` in `declarator = initializer` an assignment operator?

Is `declarator = initializer` in a declaration an assignment expression?

My question comes from [What happens when evaluating `int x = -2147483648`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64376735/what-happens-when-evaluating-int-x-2147483648#comment113844857_64377271)

Comment: It is an "assignment-expression" used as an initializer, [C11 Standard - 6.7.9 Initialization](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `=` character in this case is *not* an assignment operator, but part of the syntax of a declaration.

This is similar to how `,` can be used as the comma operator, a separator for function arguments, or a separator for declarations.  In both cases, the language knows from the surrounding context how exactly it is being used.

Regarding the syntax `declarator = initializer`, it is not an assignment expression, however `initializer` is.  From 6.7.9p1:

```
initializer:
  assignment-expression
  {initializer-list}
  {initializer-list,}
```

Which means you can do this:

```
int x;
int y = x = 3;   // the second = is an assignment operator, the first one is not
```

Comment: Why did https://stackoverflow.com/a/64377271 mention "Per 6.7.9 11, the value of the initializer is converted as in simple assignment. Per 6.5.16.1 2 and 6.5.16 3, ...", if `int x = -2147483648` is a declaration and not an assignment?

Comment: @Tim The key words here are "as in" simple assignment, meaning that the conversion that happens on the right side of an assignment operator also happens for an initializer.  It doesn't mean that they're one in the same.